# Executing bash script via python gives syntax error

Tags: command-line, scripts, python

So, I'm trying to source a file via Python.
The code goes something like this:

```
import os
source = 'source /home/software/cadence/release2013/setup/xyz.setup p'
os.system(source)
```

This gives the following:

```
/home/software/cadence/release2013/setup/xyz.setup: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `$HT'
/home/software/cadence/release2013/setup/xyz.setup: line 23: `switch ($HT)'
```

Now, I assure you. There is nothing wrong with xyz.setup. It's been sourced countless times and by many people. Also, when I directly source it via terminal

```
source /home/software/cadence/release2013/setup/xyz.setup p
 Program Research license set
```

It works just fine!
 I'm perplexed. Can anyone help? If not this way, is there any other method to do this. I tried `subprocess.call`, however the argument cannot be passed to the file.

Here's xyz.setup even though it's definitely not a mistake in there.

```
#Source script for blabla
# Use an argument to determine the type 

set fl=false
set Usage = "Usage: source /imec/software/cadence/release2013/setup/blabla.csh [e|c|p|com]"

if ($# != 1) then
 echo ""
 echo "$Usage"
 echo " with:   e -> Educational research"
 echo "     c -> Cadence Academic Network (CAN)"
 echo "     p -> Program Research"
 echo "     com -> Commercial license"
 exit 1
else
 set option=$1
 set fl=true
endif

set OK = false
setenv HT `/usr/local/bin/hosttype`

switch ($HT)
 case LINUX
  switch (`uname -m`)
   case x86_64
    setenv CDS_AUTO_64BIT ALL
    set OK = true
    breaksw
   case i686
    set OK = true
    breaksw
   default:
    echo "Not the correct operating system, LINUX 64bit required (x86_64)"
    exit 1
    breaksw
  endsw
  breaksw
 default:
  echo "Not the correct operating system, LINUX 64bit required (x86_64)"
  exit 1
  breaksw
endsw


#if ($fl == true) then
  switch ($option)
    case e
      setenv xuxnxu 34234@dfsdfds3
      echo " license is set"

    case E
      setenv xuxnxu 34234@dfsdfds3
      echo " license is set"
      breaksw

    case c
      setenv xuxnxu 34234@dfsdfds3
      echo "CAN license set"
      breaksw

    case C
      setenv xuxnxu 34234@dfsdfds3
      echo "CAN license set"
      breaksw

    case p
      setenv xuxnxu 34234@dfsdfds3
      echo "Program Research license set"
      breaksw

    case P
      setenv xuxnxu 34234@dfsdfds3
      echo "Program Research license set"
      breaksw

    case com
      setenv xuxnxu 34234@dfsdfds3
      echo "Commercial license set"
      breaksw

    case COM
      setenv xuxnxu 34234@dfsdfds3
      echo "Commercial license set"
      breaksw

    default:
      set fl=false
      echo "Not the correct option specified"
      echo "$Usage"
      breaksw
  endsw
#endif



#bla bla 
setenv CDS_INST_DIR /home/software/cadence/release2013/bla bla
setenv CDS_DFII_BIN $CDS_INST_DIR/tools/dfII/bin
setenv CDS_FLEX_BIN $CDS_INST_DIR/tools/bin



set path= ($CDS_INST_DIR/tools/dfII/bin \
           $CDS_INST_DIR/tools/bin \
       /home/software/cadence/release2013/bla bla/tools/bin $path)


#echo "Cadence setup bla bla bla sourced"
```

Comment: You probably will need to provide xyz.setup.

Comment: Did these countless sourcings by many people been via Python? If not, then what difference does that make?

Comment: It was just to highlight the fact that the setup file being sourced does not have an error. In any case, I have added that too.

Comment: That script quite definitely isn't bash, and it certainly doesn't fit `sh`. What is it? `tcsh`?

Comment: Didn't look into it thouroughly (yet) but please, please don't use `os.system`.  `subprocess`  is supposed to replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is in `csh` syntax, however `os.system` calls the default shell `/bin/sh`. If you want your script to be properly interpreted, use

```
subprocess.call(['/bin/csh','-c','source /home/software/cadence/release2013/setup/xyz.setup'])
```

Comment: Probably should have `-c` somewhere in there (unless `csh` has a completely different set of options).

Comment: Thank you all for the help!!! That solved it. Stupid mistake by me.